# Как вставить функциональный компонент?й

Tags: reactjs, react-hook, create-react-app

Подскажите, как добавить функциональный компонент на html страницу?

Answer (score 1):

1. Подключить реакт
2. Настроить вебпак
3. Отрендерить компонент в качестве приложения на страницу в заданный контейнер

Comment: Я думаю имеется ввиду через `cdn`-ки. Тогда можно без вебпака, как тут в последнем примере https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12004/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%a4%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-stack-snippet-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-react-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-jsx

Comment: @EzioMercer, а jsx компилировать как? Или и без jsx? Ну можно, но так себе идея...

Comment: Не очень понял тебя... Код, который в скрипте `type="text/babel"` уже использует синтаксис jsx. Можешь взять код из того примера и просто вставить в `body` и запустить, он будет работать

Comment: @EzioMercer, а понял. Ты предлагаешь прям в html включать скрипт, а не отдельным файлом?

Comment: Именно. Но не то что я прям настаиваю на этом, просто мне кажется автор этого и хочет :)

Comment: Кстати я вот щас поэкспериментировал и с импортом файла так же работает: [html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmwxc.png) / [js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3Ig7.png) / [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STNWm.png). В скрин js файла не попал только "Рендеринг"

Comment: @EzioMercer, хм.. Я почему-то думал, что не сработает... Перепутал с чем-то...

Comment: Ты наверное из-за возможных импортов в jsx так подумал. Потому что с ними так не сработает, т.к. придётся тип указать `module` у скрипта, но тогда придётся убрать тип `text/babel` и тогда jsx не скомпилится